Collect holders of token (proxyble Contract)
I need to collect information about token holders.
Here is the token contract, it is proxy(bnb chain): 0x9356f6d95b8e109f4b7ce3e49d672967d3b48383
I see the use of the Mint method in it, but I don't see such a function in the implementation.
I decided to just take it through bscscan, try to find it manually through balanceOf on the implementation contract, but everything that is written in holders - says 0. So where and how should I get the information, I don't quite understand?
I had a plan like this:

View the event (mint or transfer)
write addresses from the event
And then in the balanceOf function find out the number of tokens on them.

Where am I wrong here, and if I am right, then why doesn't it work?
So I'm trying to get list of holders and amount of holdings from token Contract.

Blockchain explorers (such as BSCScan) and other offchain apps often use indexers that work in this way:

Loop through all Transfer event logs emitted by the token contract
For each of the event logs, increase/decrease an offchain calculated balance of the recipient/sender.

ad 2: Token mint and burn should emit the Transfer event as well. For mint the sender is address 0; and for burn - the recipient is address 0.

Your approach is different by reading only the current balance at the time of the call to balanceOf(), which doesn't enable retrieving transaction history nor balance changes per address. And it can produce slightly inaccurate results if some of the balances change during the time you execute the set of calls to balaceOf().
If you only want to retrieve current balances, your approach is valid.
If you also need historical balances or list of transfers per address, you can use the approach described above.

Hello! How can I track this event if the ABI does not have this event? I was trying do it, but main(proxy) and implementation contract don't have these events.
Thank you!

@dill You should use the ABI of the target contract (and address of the proxy). If that's not available, here's a generic ERC20 ABI: https://gist.github.com/veox/8800debbf56e24718f9f483e1e40c35c. The generic ERC20 ABI contains all functions and events required by the standard but doesn't contain any custom functions on top of the standard that the target contract might be using.

and should I use it to proxy contract? it's another standard, no? Did you check this smart contract? 0x9356f6d95b8e109f4b7ce3e49d672967d3b48383

@dill In this specific scenario, the 0x935...  contract is in fact a proxy contract. Its current implementation/target 0xa55... is an ERC20 token that contains several custom functions on top of the generic ERC20 functions... So if you want to interact with this token, you can use the address of the proxy, and ABI of the implementation.

Yes, but when I trying to get info from this contact about Transfer events, I get an empty array. That's why I'm asking this here, unfortunately I can't track events there. Or should I use ERC 20 ABI for the proxy contract?

@dill Empty array is often caused by the RPC provider not having sufficient data. They usually offer only latest 200 blocks or so in their free plans.

okay, thank you, I will try to use ABI from implementation Contract to proxy interact with proxy. With other rpc
